# Printing report with access generate white square

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, encoding

I am trying to print an access report with PDF creator but a strange problem is happening:

If I print the report with PDF creator I get a white square in the report (see the blow instruction):

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "E_Dossier", acFormatPDF, first & strReportName, False, , 0  ,
```

but if I open it with this instruction instead, the report is correct and I don't have white squares.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "E_Dossier"            ' , acViewPreview
```

Any  ideas please?

Comment: We may need a screenshot of such *white squares*.

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues like that in the past. What I do is I open the report in hidden preview, then export to PDF and then close the preview. That seems to deal with most of the weird differences between print and export.

Edit: This is a function I use to generate PDFs

```
Public Sub PrintReportPDF(ReportName As String, Filename As String, Optional ReportArgs As String = "", Optional WhereCondition As String = "")

DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , WhereCondition, , ReportArgs
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, Filename, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName

End Sub
```

Another thing to check is that you have a regular default printer (one that would print the report properly if the report was printed to it).

Comment: Okay, how can i do this?  I have 29000 files

Comment: I edited my post to include a function that does this for you. Also see my note about the default printer.

Answer (score 0):

i have joined an example of generated white square @Marcucciboy2

[image]